# How to tell Python to automatically use the proxy setting in Windows XP like R's internet2 option?

Tags: python, proxy

I am not super technical person. But I know that in Windows if I install R using the internet2 option then I can download whatever package I want in it.

I install Python and everytime I try to download a package or install a package (e.g. using easy_install) it fails.

What can I do to make Python automatically detect my proxy settings and just install the packages?

Answer (score 10):

Set up environment variable `http_proxy` / `https_proxy` to `http://your-proxy-server-address:proxy-port`

> The urlopen() function works transparently with proxies which do not
>   require authentication. In a Unix or Windows environment, set the
>   http_proxy, or ftp_proxy environment variables to a URL that
>   identifies the proxy server before starting the Python interpreter.
>   For example (the '%' is the command prompt):
>
> ```
> % http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
> % export http_proxy
> % python
> ...
> ```
>
> The no_proxy environment variable can be used to specify
>   hosts which shouldn’t be reached via proxy; if set, it should be a
>   comma-separated list of hostname suffixes, optionally with :port
>   appended, for example cern.ch,ncsa.uiuc.edu,some.host:8080.

Comment: I did mention Windows XP in my post. Thanks though.

Comment: @xiaodai, This works in Windows as mentioned in my answer quote. I tested it under Windows XP 32bit.

Comment: % http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
% export http_proxy
% python
is Windows cmd prompt code? Powershell? I thought it was some unix command. Also i cannot set up environment varibles in windows as I don't have adminstrative priveledge as I work in a corporate environment.

Comment: @daveL, Specify the proxy in the following form: `http://username:password@someproxy.com:3128`

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question though. I guess it's not possible to tell python to automatically use windows proxy settings, but for the time being, you have to set it yourself. Also, this answer doesn't help if you're using HTTPConnection or something, where you need to specify the proxy as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Or use the HTTP_PROXY / HTTPS_PROXY setting instead.

Comment: In some LAN scenarios, it's really hard to figure out what those values should be.