# Python 3.5.1 urllib has no attribute request

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

I have tried

```
import urllib.request
```

or

```
import urllib
```

The path for my urllib is 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/__init__.py`

I am wondering where is urlopen, or is my python module pointing to the wrong file?

Comment: Funny.  Works for me (and I have the same path).  What do you get from `os.listdir(os.path.dirname(urllib.__file__))`?

Comment: That's `['__init__.py', '__pycache__', 'error.py', 'parse.py', 'request.py', 'response.py', 'robotparser.py']`

Comment: it does sound like your paths are crossed. try `import sys;print(sys.path)` and see if any python 2 related paths appear? if so, perhaps you've got something unusual set in your PYTHONPATH in your shell environment?

Comment: And, for the record, `import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlopen` works fine for me.  `import urllib; urllib.request.urlopen` would raise the `AttributeError` that you are seeing.

Comment: Can you successfully execute `from urllib.request import urlopen` ?

Are you certain you're executing from Python3?

Did you already import `urllib` earlier in the script?

Full traceback may be helpful.

Comment: `print(sys.path)` shows paths for python 3.5 libraries.. none of python 2

Comment: Somehow this worked guys... 

`import urllib;
from urllib.request import urlopen` which is kind of odd but it worked!

Answer (score 149):

According to [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1215580), you have to use the following:

```
import urllib.request
```

The reason is:

> With packages, like this, you sometimes need to explicitly import the
> piece you want. That way, the urllib module doesn't have to load
> everything up just because you wanted one small part.

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't work for me. I'm using python `3.5.2`

Comment: changed import urllib to import urllib.request and nothing else and it started working again

Comment: still not quite sure why it works in that way but this does the trick, thanks.

Comment: Some interesting background information can be found [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue36701). The same applies for example to `email.message` submodule. Basically the `os.path` is the only submodule in the stdlib that breaks this rule.

Comment: as of 2022-09-29, the links is dead.

Comment: Worked! Python 3.12

Answer (score 28):

Use this way

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('http://216.58.192.142',timeout=1)
```

Comment: if one, like me, migrates the code from python2.7 to python3, changing previously used urllib2 to urllib this way will help too!

Answer (score 5):

In My case what i did was that i created a file "http.py" so changing that name to "http_my.py" solved that problem .same as @JohnnyFun

Answer (score 4):

In python 3.6.x this worked for me, this way I did not have to change the code at all:

```
import urllib.request as urllib
```

Comment: This will lead to confusion if another person ever needs to edit your code.

Comment: Probably not 'will' but 'may, but I agree if you write a code that may be managed by others it is better to write a comment about the workaround used, so it does not come with a surprise for maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing above worked for you, try renaming your python module.

In my particular case, the issue was that the file I was running was called `http.py`. Once I changed the name to `test-http.py`, importing urllib.request resolved the error `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'`

I had noticed that further up the exception trace the internal packages were trying to fetch a module called `http`, so guessing my module's name was wonkin stuff up...

Comment: This fixed an issue ! What can also cause this error is if you have file named http.py anywhere in you working directory .  Note that this can brake other libraries that depend on urllib ex. http.client

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using Python 3.8.2.

I checked the _*init*_.py file located at /usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/ and its empty, which means you can not make a fully qualified access using only import urllib. In this case, you have to use import urllib.request.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your title does not have the same name as one of the python modules. i.e, if the name of your file is "socket.py" or "https.py". You will encounter the Attribute Error.
Good Luck

Comment: This is a duplicate of a number of existing answers. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.

Answer (score 0):

i did this and it worked for me :

```
from urllib3 import request
```

try that

Answer (score 0):

i have a same issue at using python version 3.8, but you can use urllib with http protocol (non https) like url = "http://www.google.com" for test maybe this just only used for http protocol request but not for https "correct me if i wrong thank you^" so how we can do that-:

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://www.google.com/"

headers = {'User-Agent': "duckduckgo.com-bot"}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

print(response)
```

reference document from python 3.8 -> (`https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.request.html`)

you can refer what you need -> ctrl+f urllib.request + urllib.request.urlopen

Answer (score -3):

```
import urllib.request as urllib
```

then in the code call urlopen function

example:

```
test = urllib.urlopen("----")
```