# Why is my atom editor giving a traceback when I'm importing a package?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt')

counts = dict()
for line in fhand:
    words = line.decode().split()
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
print(counts)
```

Traceback

[image]

And the python version that I'm using is 3.8.5

Comment: That works for me in 3.8.5 on macOS.

Comment: This Question will repeated. Please try this. Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042152/python-3-5-1-urllib-has-no-attribute-request