# Detect proxy provided to pip install

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I am looking at a package (which can be installed using pip) code which requires a file from internet.

Pip provides an option to mention proxy details as shown below

```
pip install --proxy="http://user:pass@proxyserver:port" package_name
```

But the same proxy details are not identified by the *setup.py* script of the package. When I modified the *setup.py* file using the following lines, it works fine.

```
proxy_url = 'http://user:pass@proxy:port/'
proxy_url_https = 'http://user:pass@proxy:port/'
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_url, 'https': proxy_url_https})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

But how can the *setup.py* file be modified to check if the proxy is provided and take the necessary steps?

Comment: Set up environment variable `http_proxy` / `https_proxy`. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247981/how-to-tell-python-to-automatically-use-the-proxy-setting-in-windows-xp-like-rs

Comment: but, what if the user who is installing using pip doesn't set environment variable and provide proxy settings to pip.