# how to capture Visual studio code http(s) Python requests

Tags: python, http, https, proxy

I wanted to know how to capture http(s) traffic from python codes that run on visual studio code

I tried using fiddler however it does not capture traffic from that python task. I even tried running it just over CMD and connecting the PID to fiddler it still didn't capture anything

Comment: You need to tell Python to use the proxy, see e.g. this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/17247981/150978

Comment: @Robert A normal Proxy will not give you a look into the encrypted traffic. And one with SSL MitM is more complex to set up.

Comment: What do you think Fiddler is? It is a http proxy with Mitm capabilities. But for capturing traffic you need to make the programs use the proxy. Most Windows programs use the proxy from Windows Internet settings which Fiddler automatically sets to itself but some programs like Python need manual proxy config. That is why I linked to this old question. Not that you also need to add the Fiddler root CA cert to the trusted certificate store of the program/framework like Python. Not sure how this can be done for your Python scripts.